# Using SimpleDateFormat as a String for filenames

Tags: java, string, date, time

I'm currently creating an app that saves data into the disk. I want the file name of the files to be the current date. I tried using *SimpleDateFormat* for this purpose, but I don't know how I could convert it to a string. Its toString() method isn't being overrided from Object, therefore I don't get a valid result back.

This is the code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
...
ImageIO.write(capture, "png", new File(sdf.toString() + ".png"));
```

How do I represent that date/time format as a string?

Complete code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Screenshot {

    private static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

    public static void fullScreenshot() {
        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());

        try {
            BufferedImage capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
            ImageIO.write(capture, "png", new File(sdf.format(new Date()) + ".png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Thrown exception at IO file save");
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            System.err.println("Insufficient permissions or explosion while screenshoting");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `sdf.format(new Date())`. A `DateFormat` is not initialized with any date, you have to pass the date to its `format` method (or a string to its `parse` one).

Comment: The output of this is indeed a string, but it is converting the colons (:) to slashes (/) from the format. How do I prevent that?

Comment: @Aborted Could you provide your code? This is probably not due to the `DateFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

you should do

```
sdf.format( new Date() );
```

This will work!

Comment: This is converting the colons to slashes. The output is coming back as yyyy-MM-dd HH/mm/ss/SSS. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Aborted If you are on  a NTFS file-system (like Windows) you can't have colons in file names, maybe that's why (i may be wrong)

Answer (score 0):

only pass the date on format method

```
sdf.format(new Date().getTime())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
sdf.format(new Date().getTime());
```

or

```
String fName = String.valueOf(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime())); // it ll give you current timestamp

ImageIO.write(capture, "png", new File(fName + ".png"));
```

or

```
ImageIO.write(capture, "png", new File("Name" + fName + ".png"));
```

in both case `Date()` from `java.sql` package.